# Is it possible at all in Excel to draw a circular arrow that starts and ends on two cells in the same column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is an image of the type of shape I am trying to draw in Excel:

[image]

I am not able to find any shape in Excel that can be used to draw an arrow of this nature. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

Just select the shape named "square bracket left (or right)".
You can then adjust the corner radius, having the shape morph from rectangle to perfect half-circle. You can add arrows etc. as well.

Answer (score 2):

On my Excel for Microsoft 365, I search the arrow in Icons (Insert tab > Illustrations > Icons), then choose one icon to insert.

[image]

You may resize it or rotate it. If needed, you may also rigjt-click it > Convert to Shape.

[image]

Comment: You can also go to Insert->Shapes, select Coonector: Curve Arrow.